# Attach disabled display device with WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

My problem is enabling a disabled monitor with `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx`. I guess it is not rocket science but after some digging it still looks impossible. I found a way to disable all secondary displays basing on Microsoft code sample found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162617(v=vs.85).aspx). While it needed only basic tweaking to work, re-attaching never worked. What I was trying to do was:

**1. Initialize DisplayDevice**

```
BOOL            FoundSecondaryDisp = FALSE;
DWORD           DispNum = 0;
DISPLAY_DEVICE  DisplayDevice;
LONG            Result;
TCHAR           szTemp[200];
int             i = 0;
DEVMODE   defaultMode;
ZeroMemory(&DisplayDevice, sizeof(DisplayDevice));
DisplayDevice.cb = sizeof(DisplayDevice);
```

**2. Find all devices**

```
while (EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, DispNum, &DisplayDevice, 0))
{
    ZeroMemory(&defaultMode, sizeof(DEVMODE));
    defaultMode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
    //point 3 goes here
}
```

**3. Detect detached device**

```
if (!(DisplayDevice.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP))
```

**4. Enable device**

```
DEVMODE    DevMode;
ZeroMemory(&DevMode, sizeof(DevMode));
DevMode.dmSize = sizeof(DevMode);
DevMode.dmFields = DM_POSITION | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;
DevMode.dmPelsWidth = 1920;
DevMode.dmPelsHeight = 1080;
Result = ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(DisplayDevice.DeviceName, &DevMode, NULL, CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY, NULL);
ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Last point returns DISP_CHANGE_FAILED code and it does not enable any display. Did anyone have some similar experience?

Comment: Thank you for input! The monitor **was** disabled with `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx()`, my full test program disables secondary displays and them tries to enable them back, both using `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx()`.

Comment: Regarding 4, is there any chance to query the modes of the disabled device to avoid hard coded values? Or use a kind of automatic mode?

Answer (score 5):

Try adding CDS_NORESET to your first call to ChangeDisplaySettingsEx.

This one works:

```
ChangeDisplaySettingsEx((LPCWSTR)DisplayDevice.DeviceName, &DevMode, NULL, CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY | CDS_NORESET, NULL);
ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

This one does NOT work:

```
ChangeDisplaySettingsEx((LPCWSTR)DisplayDevice.DeviceName, &DevMode, NULL, CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY | CDS_RESET, NULL);
ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

This one also does NOT work:

```
ChangeDisplaySettingsEx((LPCWSTR)DisplayDevice.DeviceName, &DevMode, NULL, CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY, NULL);
ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was automating displays like 2 years ago but maybe I will need it again some time ;) Or maybe someone will need it some day!