# Enable a disabled screen using ChangeDisplaySettingsEx

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, monitor

I'm using WinAPI **ChangeDisplaySettingsEx** to switch my windows 10 screens config.

There are more than two screens, so ScreenSwitch.exe is not enough for me.

I referenced this:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/178027/How-to-create-a-display-switcher-for-Windows-XP?msg=3850767#xx3850767xx


and successed disable a screen in these code:

```
string displayName = @"\\.\DISPLAY3";
DEVMODE devMode= new DEVMODE();
devMode.dmPosition.x = 0;
devMode.dmPosition.y = 0;
devMode.dmPelsWidth = 0;
devMode.dmPelsHeight = 0;
devMode.dmFields = DEVMODE_Flags.DM_PELSHEIGHT | DEVMODE_Flags.DM_PELSWIDTH | DEVMODE_Flags.DM_POSITION;
devMode.dmSize = (ushort)Marshal.SizeOf(devMode);
ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(displayName, ref devMode, IntPtr.Zero, (int)(DeviceFlags.CDS_RESET | DeviceFlags.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY), IntPtr.Zero);
```

But I can't enable screen:

```
...
devMode.dmPosition.x = -3840;
devMode.dmPosition.y = -1059;
devMode.dmPelsWidth = 3840;
devMode.dmPelsHeight = 2160;
...
```

**ChangeDisplaySettingsEx** got -1 result means CHANGE_FAILED


I guess that screen has disabled, so enable it need more information?


I tried save DEVMODE when the screen enabled, and send it to ChangeDisplaySettingsEx when screen disabled. Not works.


Thanks for any suggest

Comment: Try: `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(displayName, ref devMode, IntPtr.Zero, (int)(DeviceFlags.CDS_NORESET | DeviceFlags.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY), IntPtr.Zero);
ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);` and tell me if it useful.

Comment: Refer: [Attach disabled display device with WinAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35033525/attach-disabled-display-device-with-winapi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Strive Sun's answer.

It work.


I can't enable my "\.\DISPLAY3" directly,

My "Screen2" will be active first, although the argument is "Screen3".

But it can workaround easily, like this:

```
enableScreen(2);
enableScreen(3);
disableScreen(2);
```

I also tried use **EnumDisplayDevices** to get the deviceName of my monitor. 

I got "\.\DISPLAY3\Monitor0".


But it will fail in ChangeDisplaySettingsEx, got -5 result (means BAD_PARAM).

Comment: Glad to help you. You can mark your answer to end this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I fight for this issue for three days.
And I can't find a full sample for this.
And I find a sluction for open the disable screen in try and error.
You need to reset the disable screen and reset the primary screen.

This is my test code to disable and enable screen code.
I want to help another one for same issue.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
//ref:
//https://blog.lohr.dev/primary-display-windows
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61429285/enable-a-disabled-screen-using-changedisplaysettingsex
//https://zouzhongliang.com/index.php/2018/06/16/changedisplaysettingsexhanshu/
//https://www.asawicki.info/news_1637_how_to_change_display_mode_using_winapi

namespace LEDPlayground.Countrollers.WindowsScreenSetting
{
    class WindowsScreenAPITest
    {
        public WindowsScreenAPITest()
        {
            CloseInactiveAndStartInactive();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// If you want to enable a disable device.
        /// You need to change device and reChage the primary device like me.
        /// </summary>
        public void CloseInactiveAndStartInactive()
        {
            GetDisplayInfo();
            CloseInactiveAndResetInactive();
            ResetPrimaryDevice();
        }
        public void GetDisplayInfo()
        {
            ddActive.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(ddActive);
            ddInactive.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(ddInactive);
            uint iDeviceCntr = 0;
            DISPLAY_DEVICE dd = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
            dd.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(dd);
            while (EnumDisplayDevices(null, iDeviceCntr, ref dd, 0))
            {
                DEVMODE dMode = new DEVMODE();
                dMode.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(dMode);
                if (EnumDisplaySettings(dd.DeviceName, ENUM_REGISTRY_SETTINGS, ref dMode))
                {
                    //if (dMode.dmPelsHeight > 0 && dMode.dmPelsWidth > 0)
                    {
                        if ((dd.StateFlags & DisplayDeviceStateFlags.PrimaryDevice) ==
                             DisplayDeviceStateFlags.PrimaryDevice)
                        {
                            ddActive = dMode;
                            szActiveDeviceName = dd.DeviceName;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ddInactive = dMode;
                            szInactiveDeviceName = dd.DeviceName;
                        }
                    }
                }
                iDeviceCntr++;
            }
        }
        public void CloseInactiveAndResetInactive()
        {
            var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DEVMODE>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ddInactive));
            var temp2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DEVMODE>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ddInactive));
            temp.dmPelsHeight = 0;
            temp.dmPelsWidth = 0;
            ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(szInactiveDeviceName, ref temp,
              IntPtr.Zero, (int)(CDSFlags.CDS_RESET | CDSFlags.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY), IntPtr.Zero);

            var ddd = ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(szInactiveDeviceName, ref temp2,
              IntPtr.Zero, (int)(CDSFlags.CDS_NORESET | CDSFlags.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY2), IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        public void ResetPrimaryDevice()
        {
            uint iDeviceCntr = 0;
            DISPLAY_DEVICE dd = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
            dd.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(dd);
            while (EnumDisplayDevices(null, iDeviceCntr, ref dd, 0))
            {
                DEVMODE dMode = new DEVMODE();
                dMode.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(dMode);
                if (EnumDisplaySettings(dd.DeviceName, ENUM_REGISTRY_SETTINGS, ref dMode))
                {
                    if ((dd.StateFlags & DisplayDeviceStateFlags.PrimaryDevice) ==
                         DisplayDeviceStateFlags.PrimaryDevice)
                    {
                        ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(dd.DeviceName, ref dMode,
                            IntPtr.Zero, (int)(CDSFlags.CDS_RESET | CDSFlags.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY), IntPtr.Zero);
                    }
                }
                iDeviceCntr++;
            }
        }
        //Member variables
        DEVMODE ddActive = new DEVMODE();
        DEVMODE ddInactive = new DEVMODE();
        string szActiveDeviceName = string.Empty;
        string szInactiveDeviceName = string.Empty;
        const int ENUM_REGISTRY_SETTINGS = -2;
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool EnumDisplayDevices(string lpDevice,
           uint iDevNum, ref DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice, uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName,
               int modeNum, ref DEVMODE devMode);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern DISP_CHANGE ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(string lpszDeviceName,
               ref DEVMODE lpDevMode, IntPtr hwnd, uint dwflags, IntPtr lParam);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct DEVMODE
        {
            public const int CCHDEVICENAME = 32;
            public const int CCHFORMNAME = 32;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCHDEVICENAME)]
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
            public string dmDeviceName;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(32)]
            public Int16 dmSpecVersion;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(34)]
            public Int16 dmDriverVersion;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(36)]
            public Int16 dmSize;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(38)]
            public Int16 dmDriverExtra;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(40)]
            public DM dmFields;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(44)]
            Int16 dmOrientation;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(46)]
            Int16 dmPaperSize;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(48)]
            Int16 dmPaperLength;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(50)]
            Int16 dmPaperWidth;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(52)]
            Int16 dmScale;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(54)]
            Int16 dmCopies;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(56)]
            Int16 dmDefaultSource;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(58)]
            Int16 dmPrintQuality;

            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(44)]
            public POINTL dmPosition;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(52)]
            public Int32 dmDisplayOrientation;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(56)]
            public Int32 dmDisplayFixedOutput;

            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(60)]
            public short dmColor;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(62)]
            public short dmDuplex;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(64)]
            public short dmYResolution;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(66)]
            public short dmTTOption;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(68)]
            public short dmCollate;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(72)]
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCHFORMNAME)]
            public string dmFormName;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(102)]
            public Int16 dmLogPixels;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(104)]
            public Int32 dmBitsPerPel;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(108)]
            public Int32 dmPelsWidth;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(112)]
            public Int32 dmPelsHeight;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(116)]
            public Int32 dmDisplayFlags;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(116)]
            public Int32 dmNup;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(120)]
            public Int32 dmDisplayFrequency;

        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct DISPLAY_DEVICE
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int cb;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
            public string DeviceName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
            public string DeviceString;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public DisplayDeviceStateFlags StateFlags;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
            public string DeviceID;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
            public string DeviceKey;
        }

        [Flags()]
        public enum DisplayDeviceStateFlags: int
        {
            AttachedToDesktop = 0x1,
            MultiDriver = 0x2,
            PrimaryDevice = 0x4,
            MirroringDriver = 0x8,
            VGACompatible = 0x16,
            Removable = 0x20,
            ModesPruned = 0x8000000,
            Remote = 0x4000000,
            Disconnect = 0x2000000
        }

        [Flags()]
        public enum DM: int
        {
            Orientation = 0x1,
            PaperSize = 0x2,
            PaperLength = 0x4,
            PaperWidth = 0x8,
            Scale = 0x10,
            Position = 0x20,
            NUP = 0x40,
            DisplayOrientation = 0x80,
            Copies = 0x100,
            DefaultSource = 0x200,
            PrintQuality = 0x400,
            Color = 0x800,
            Duplex = 0x1000,
            YResolution = 0x2000,
            TTOption = 0x4000,
            Collate = 0x8000,
            FormName = 0x10000,
            LogPixels = 0x20000,
            BitsPerPixel = 0x40000,
            PelsWidth = 0x80000,
            PelsHeight = 0x100000,
            DisplayFlags = 0x200000,
            DisplayFrequency = 0x400000,
            ICMMethod = 0x800000,
            ICMIntent = 0x1000000,
            MediaType = 0x2000000,
            DitherType = 0x4000000,
            PanningWidth = 0x8000000,
            PanningHeight = 0x10000000,
            DisplayFixedOutput = 0x20000000
        }

        enum DISP_CHANGE: int
        {
            Successful = 0,
            Restart = 1,
            Failed = -1,
            BadMode = -2,
            NotUpdated = -3,
            BadFlags = -4,
            BadParam = -5,
            BadDualView = -1
        }

        public struct POINTL
        {
            public long x;
            public long y;
        }

        enum CDSFlags
        {
            CDS_NORESET = 0x10000000,
            CDS_RESET = 0x40000000,
            CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY = 0x00000001,
            CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY2 = 0x1,
            CDS_SET_PRIMARY = 0x00000010
        };
    }
}
```